# How to choose MappingContext in spring-data-jpa (2x) + spring-rest-webmvc?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I've got a Module A that provides authentication through users, groups and related classes. This module uses `org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.6.0.RELEASE` to access this data from a database. Of note might be that Module A uses a custom BaseRepository configured by extending JpaRepositoryFactoryBean, but removing this does not resolve the issue below.

A second Module B also has some classes and repositories to manage, unrelated to the Module A classes, again using `spring-data-jpa` for storage, but connected to a different database. This project exposes it's repositories via REST using `org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:2.1.0.RELEASE`. Module B uses the classes in module A for authenticating users, but does not manipulate those class instances nor does it store any references.

The issue I'm having now is that my module B REST APIs work flawlessly when Module A is not present (or with an older version not yet using spring-data-jpa), but when it is I present it breaks on creating self referential links with the below stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create self link for class Document! No persistent entity found!
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.getSelfLinkFor(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:81) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.1.0.M1.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.toResource(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:64) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.1.0.M1.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.toResource(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:32) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.1.0.M1.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.web.PagedResourcesAssembler.createResource(PagedResourcesAssembler.java:144) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.0.M1.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.web.PagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(PagedResourcesAssembler.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.0.M1.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.entitiesToResources(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:220) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.1.0.M1.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.resultToResources(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:207) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.1.0.M1.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResource(RepositoryEntityController.java:135) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.1.0.M1.jar:na]
```

See also: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java#L80

It looks to be talking to the wrong `MappingContext` in the `RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport`, even if my `org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories` contains all the repositoryBeanNames from both Module A and Module B.

Does anyone know how I can enforce the use of a particular MappingContext, perhaps through my extension of `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration`?

** **Edit** **
Here's an GitHub repository illustrating the problem:
https://github.com/timtebeek/dual-data-jpa-rest-webmvc

It's since been reported as a bug on the data-rest project:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-312

Comment: Do you still see this in 2.1.0.RELEASE?

Comment: Wauw, euhm, I'll check; I was using Spring 4 which gives some conflicts with the 2.1.0.RELEASE version, so I'll need to switch back to 3.2.x to test this in a bit. I'll update as soon as I've got a working version again.

Comment: @OliverGierke I can confirm this issue also occurs with spring-data-jpa:1.6.0.RELEASE and spring-data-rest-webmvc:2.1.0.RELEASE. Is there any additional information that I can make available to you to help debug this?

Comment: It's pretty hard to judge without finding out more about how your modules are interacting with each other, how they're bootstrapped, what the ApplicationContext structure looks like etc. Any chance you can come up with a very stripped down version of your app to reproduce the error?

Comment: Thanks for considering this; I'll try to whip something up on github and post a link when done, but it could take a small while to replicate while not leaking any company code. :)

Comment: @OliverGierke Here's a greatly reduced version of my project, sans any identifying code or comments: https://github.com/timtebeek/dual-data-jpa-rest-webmvc There's contact details in there should you want to reach me outside this cramped comment box. :) I very much appreciate you having a look.
(And I've read your blog; there's probably some things I could/should do differently, but right now it mostly matches my actual project.)

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me today

I was trying to query a specific Entity

I fix it creating the repository of that class

In your case it'll be

```
@Repository
public interface DocumentRepository extends JpaRepository<Document, Long> {
}
```

also doing all the needed configuration to use jpa repositories. [Look here](https://github.com/charlires/rest-api-template/blob/master/src/main/java/com/charlires/example/config/JpaConfig.java)

I hope that hepls.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm afraid the issue is a bit more complicated here. You can [see the git repo I use to illustrate the problem here](https://github.com/timtebeek/dual-data-jpa-rest-webmvc/). It [already contains a class similar to your snippet](https://github.com/timtebeek/dual-data-jpa-rest-webmvc/blob/master/documents/src/main/java/com/github/timtebeek/ddjrw/documents/repo/DocumentRepo.java). The issue only arises here when it combined with a second Spring-data-jpa project, as indicated in the bug report: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-312