# Spring Data REST Joined Inheritance Issue

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a Spring Data `Repository` over a single JPA entity.  This entity is subclassed via joined inheritance.

Spring Data REST seems to have a problem interpreting this structure, at least automatically.  Or maybe I'm misunderstanding the usage of `Inheritance.JOINED`

Any request for any entity with an `Event` returns the following:

```
{
    cause: null,
    message: "Cannot create self link for class com.foo.event.SubEvent! No persistent entity found!"
}
```

Maybe I'm asking too much for this project to know how to handle this, but is there a workaround that would group all of my `Events` under the same `/events`? Maybe even allowing me to filter on type?

I've left the basics of the application structure below.

*Event.java*

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
  @Type(value = SubEvent.class), 
  ...
})
...
public class Event {
    @Id
    private long id;
    ...
}
```

*SubEvent.java*

```
@Entity
public class SubEvent extends Event {
    private String code;
    ...
}
```

*EventRepository.java*

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "events")
public interface EventRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Event, Long> {
    ...    
}
```

Comment: The issue isn't only with `JOINED` inheritance type. The same issue is found when using `SINGLE_TABLE`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing using `Discriminator` to let JPA understand what subclass to use for a given object (how does it know otherwise?).

I tend to use abstract classes for table-per-subclass hireachies, so here's an example adapted to that for you:

*Event.java*

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    public String type;
}
```

*SubEvent.java*

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("subevent")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "event_id")
public class PeeringService extends Service {
    private String code;
}
```

With the above code, you'll notice something odd however - when generating the resource path for one of these objects, it assumes you have a `Repository` for each subclass, and generates something like this:

```
{
  "type" : "subevent",
  "code" : "bacon",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/subEvents/1"
    },
    "peeringService" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/subEvents/1"
    }
  }
}
```

This is pretty easy to fix though, you just need to add the following annotation to your base class:

```
@RestResource(path = "events")
```

And it will generate the resource paths you'd expect!

Hope this helps :)

Comment: this solution with spring-data-rest 2.5.1 doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'm running `2.4.4.RELEASE` (the version recommended by the current `spring-boot`).

I'll give it a shot on the newer version next week :)

Comment: in my case seems that only one (non-deterministic) of the repositories (with the same path) handled the request, this resulted in a rest controller delivering only part of the rows (only the ones the repository was responsible for). Let me know how your test goes, I'm keen to know the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I tried you classes out in a simple spring boot project nd they didn't give me any problems and I couldn't reproduce the issue you are having. However,  search on the error message you describe gives a couple of posts that suggest that you need to create a `SubEvent` repository even f you don't use it, and that the problem arises in more complicated projects, such as using REST.

Reference: [Cannot create self link for class X. No persistent entity found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171008/cannot-create-self-link-for-class-x-no-persistent-entity-found).

[How to choose MappingContext in spring-data-jpa (2x) + spring-rest-webmvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23763585/how-to-choose-mappingcontext-in-spring-data-jpa-2x-spring-rest-webmvc)

So, try adding a SubEvent repository:

```
interface SubEventRepository extends CrudRepository<SubEvent, Long> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem has nothing to do with JPA, but it is rather a circular serialization problem. As you haven't shown your entity, I can only suppose that the Subevent entity has a relationship to another (Sub)Event and that one Subevent references itself, which leads to the problem. Of course it is also possible that the relationship is not a direct one, but rather through some other entity classes, like SubEvent -> EntityG -> Event.

To solve it, simply use a [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) in which you map only all the fields of the SubEvent except those that produce the circular dependency.

Comment: Hey Andrei.  The entities are probably just named poorly for this exercise, as I just scrubbed them for the sake of the question.  There are in fact no circular references in this model :-/

Comment: In order to find the cause and eventually to make sure there is no circular reference begin to comment out JPA-mapped property one-by-one, till you find what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out quite a few options and none worked as expected, and always had problem on one point (links generation, repository mapping, url mapping and so on).

Even for separated repositories (one for each subtype) I had no success. My "dirty as hell but working" solution was to post-process links for all subtypes using an implementation of `ResourceProcessor`. This implementation basically replaced the subtype name with the type name on each link present on the resource.

Additionally a `RelProvider` was introduced to handle properties names of different types.